# Shared Exceptions between HTTP and RPC

Tags: nestjs

Hi,

We have a NestJS application that is reachable both by HTTP and gRPC (using a custom RPC strategy).

Whilst they don't share the same *routes*, they do share some code. For example, a service to lookup resources from the database. We initially followed [the documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters) and used Exceptions filters to manage HTTP response status code. This means that service throws an instance of NotFoundException when a resource cannot be found.

However now that we're trying to integrate with the RPC exception handler, we found that any type of exception that isn't a instance of RpcException will be considered a Internal Server Error by the RPC microservice, including HttpExceptions.

After looking at the documentation and the source code I cannot find a way to share exceptions correctly between those two microservices, but I can be totally mistaken.

Is there a way to share code between HTTP and RPC services while still reporting exceptions accurately through both protocol?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a global exception filter / or interceptor to the gRPC microservice, that would transform every thrown `HttpException`. At the moment there's no generic exception class for each transport type.

Comment: I just tried to define a Global Filter but encountered [this issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/316).

Answer (score 0):

Replying to my own question: based on [reported issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/316), this is not supported when in the context of an Hybrid Application.

My project requirements have changed however so I am unlikely to investigate further.